# Are MSTests executed as a single assembly, even though they are located in different assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, mstest

I noticed that there is a difference between the path returned by

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

and the path returned by

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

when running some mstests per assembly and when running them all together.

---

In the current example I have a common project which is referenced by two unit test projects *Test1* and *Test2*. In the common project I have the following class:

```
public static class PathProvider
{
    private static string GetWritingPathForTest(string testName) =>
        "C:/file - " + testName + ".txt";

    public static string Path1 => Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    public static string Path2 =>
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    public static string Path3 => AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;


    public static void WritePaths(string testName)
    {
        var writingPath = GetWritingPathForTest(testName);
        File.WriteAllText(writingPath, Path1 + Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(writingPath, Path2 + Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(writingPath, Path3 + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

In the test methods I am just calling the `WritePaths` method to see what it is writing out. When executing the first test, then the second one, the results are like the following:

**Test1:**

> ...\Test1\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test1\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test1\bin\Debug

**Test2:**

> ...\Test2\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test2\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test2\bin\Debug

Where by `...` I have replaced the whole path which is the same and unimportant in this context.

So each test has been ran within its own assembly, nothing surprisingly by now, at least for me.

Here comes the strange part - If I am running these tests using the *Run All* button, the results are like these:

**Test1:**

> ...\Test1\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test1\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test1\bin\Debug

**Test2:**

> ...\Test2\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test1\bin\Debug
>
> ...\Test2\bin\Debug

Notice that the second entry is the same for them both. My question is - Why `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)` returns the same path even though the tests are located in different assemblies, when run with *Run All* option?

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns whatever is executing the code.  This does _not_ correspond to where the code is located (such as separate Projects/DLLs).  Your output looks like expected behavior to me.  Same would be true if you had one executable running code from multiple referenced projects.  I'd use `typeof(YourClassType).Assembly` instead.

Comment: @Zer0 what is strange for me is that the Test1 assembly is running the tests for Test2 assembly also. Why should this happen?

Comment: Not positive, but I'm also not sure how you're calling this method.  That said, I really don't think _executing assembly_ is what you care about.  I think you actually want the  _assembly where the type is defined_.

Comment: The output does not tell you anything about the assembly.  Which is the "common project" whose name you didn't mention.  You could only see where that DLL is stored.  One of the very untrivial thing that a test execution framework must do is help the CLR find assemblies.  Hard to do correctly since DLLs can be scattered in project directories and the default search path of the test engine is not the same as the tests.  Unspecified, but it surely uses AppDomain.AssemblyResolve.  It is happy with the location of the first test, you do have a copy of that DLL there.  Not a good thing.

Comment: @Zer0 I am not having a problem, so I am not looking for a solution, but I am wondering why the unit tests are behaving like that.

Comment: @HansPassant this behavior of unit tests executing assembly have created a tricky bug on a project I have been working on these days, this is why I was asking about the behavior of unit tests executing assembly. The fact is that I reproduced this behavior on a simple console application (the common mysterious project) and two simple unit test projects referencing it. So, what I understand is that I can not rely that the executing assembly of a Unit Test project can be the assembly in which the test is defined. Is this right?